# du only for directories

Tags: shell, du

In C-Shell, how can I get the same output as `du -sh ./*` but without listing the files in the root dir, i.e. just a list of subdirectories in ./ and the sizes of all their contents?

Comment: I don't get it. I tried `sh` and `csh` and except for ordering the output is the same. (I have to admit that I am actually using `bash` and `tcsh`.)

Comment: @Shi I should clarify: the comment about C-Shell is just to specify what I'm using. I'm seeking another command or options that will give me the same result, but without listing the sizes of the files in ./

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Add a trailing slash, like:

```
du -sh ./*/
```

Comment: This is one of the fastest Stack Exchange fixes I've had. +2 if I could.

Comment: Note: if the `-s` is dropped, it becomes recursive. Note: piping to `sort -h` will sort by the human-readable size ([`-h` flag was introduced in GNU `sort` in 2009](https://serverfault.com/a/156648/193406)).

Comment: @Evgeni, thanks for the mention about dropping -s makes it recursive. For some reason that was hard to find, but you had it.

Comment: Show also the hidden directory :

`du -shc .[^.]* /* | sort -hr`

Answer (score 28):

Duplicate answer as above just adding sort and flag to display size in a human-readable format

```
du -sh */ | sort -hr
```

Outputs:

```
44G     workspace/
24G     Downloads/
6.2G    Videos/
1.5G    Pictures/
189M    Music/
12M     Documents/
8.0K    Postman/
8.0K    Desktop/
```

You may also like to add a threshold

```
du -sh */ -t 100M | sort -hr
```

Outputs:

```
44G     workspace/
24G     Downloads/
6.2G    Videos/
1.5G    Pictures/
189M    Music/
```

man page for `du` and `sort`

```
DU(1)                                                                                        

NAME
       du - estimate file space usage

SYNOPSIS
       du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
       du [OPTION]... --files0-from=F

DESCRIPTION
       Summarize disk usage of the set of FILEs, recursively for directories.

       -h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

       -s, --summarize
              display only a total for each argument

       -t, --threshold=SIZE
          exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive, or entries greater than SIZE if negative


SORT(1)                                                                                          

NAME
       sort - sort lines of text files

SYNOPSIS
       sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...
       sort [OPTION]... --files0-from=F

DESCRIPTION
       Write sorted concatenation of all FILE(s) to standard output.

       -h, --human-numeric-sort
              compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

       -r, --reverse
              reverse the result of comparisons
```

Comment: Please note that using `| sort -hr` the output will be buffered, whereas `df` by itself outputs a stream as it works.

Comment: good to know :+1: Thanks